# How to use scala combinators to give arbitrary values to expressions

Tags: scala, parsing

Lets say I want to parse a string in scala, and every time there were parenthesis nested within each other I would multiply some number with itself . Ex
(()) +() + ((())) with number=3 would be 3*3 + 3 + 3*3*3. How would I do this with scala combinators.

```
class SimpleParser extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def Base:Parser[Int] = """(""" ~remainder ~ """)"""  
  def Plus = atom ~ '+' ~ remainder 
  def Parens = Base
  def remainder:Parser[Int] =(Next|Start) }
```

How would I make it so that every time an atom is parsed the number would multiply by itself, and then what was inside the atom will also be parsed?
would I put a method after the atom def like

```
def Base:Parser[Int] = """(""" ~remainder ~ """)""" ^^(2*paser(remainder))
```

? I don't understand how to do this because of the recursive nature of it, as if I find parenthesis, I must then multiply by three times whatever is in these parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easiest if you build up the number from the inside out. For the parenthetical groups, we start with the base case (which will result in simply the number itself), and then add the number again for each nesting. For the sum, we start with a single parenthetical group and then optionally add summands until we run out:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class SimpleParser(number: Int) extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def base: Parser[Int] = literal("()").map(_ => number)
  def pars: Parser[Int] = base | ("(" ~> pars <~ ")").map(_ + number)

  def plus: Parser[Int] = "+" ~> expr
  def expr: Parser[Int] = (pars ~ opt(plus).map(_.getOrElse(0))).map {
    case first ~ rest => first + rest
  }
}

object ParserWith3 extends SimpleParser(3)
```

And then:

```
scala> ParserWith3.parseAll(ParserWith3.expr, "(())+()+((()))")
res0: ParserWith3.ParseResult[Int] = [1.15] parsed: 18
```

I'm using `map` because I can't stand the parsing library's little operator party, but you could replace all the `map`s with `^^` or `^^^` if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the fact that you can build right recursive rules using scala parser combinators(here `mult` appears on the right of its own definition for example):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

trait  ExprsParsers extends RegexParsers {
   val value = 3
   lazy val mult: Parser[Int] = 
     "(" ~> mult <~ ")" ^^ { _ * value }  |||
     "()" ^^ { _ => value }

   lazy val plus: Parser[Int] = 
     (mult <~ "+") ~ plus ^^ { case m ~ p => m + p } ||| 
     mult
}
```

To use that code you simply create a structure that inherits ExprsParsers, e.g. :

```
object MainObj extends ExprsParsers {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(parseAll(plus, "() + ()"))  //[1.8] parsed: 6
        println(parseAll(plus, "() + (())")) //[1.10] parsed: 12
        println(parseAll(plus, "((())) + ()"))  //[1.12] parsed: 30
    }
}
```

check [scala source file for parser](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L1) for any operator you don't understand.